# Active Record Resolution of Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to add a block of code that executes when a scope resolves? For example:

```
@users = User.where(name: "...") #doesn't resolve yet
@users.resolved do
  puts "loaded: #{@users.map(&:name)}"
end

@users = @users.limit(4) # doesn't resolve yet
@users.load # resolves - hence prints loaded: user #1, user #2, ...
```